# how to present tabs in readthedocs?

Tags: html, css, read-the-docs

can I achieve a nice *tab effect* as
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/programming-guide.html#initializing-spark
to support multiple languages example?

Comment: Those are list items (`<li>`) in an unordered list `<ul>`.  The tab effect is a result of CSS magic.  Can you tag this with "html" and "css" as to receive more attention?

Comment: I am new to it so I was looking for simple solutions if any ;P